# One database within a DAG filling up transaction logs

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, transaction-log

We run a fairly large Exchange 2010 DAG with 7 servers. 3 in production where all the databases are mounted, 3 in DR where they can be transferred should production go down and a LAG server on a 4 day lag. Due to reasons I wont get into, we are not running regular backups on the Exchange server. We rely on the DAG and the LAG for replication and accept the risk of lost mail potential should something catastrophic happen. (We only have a 28 day retention policy anyway) There are 7 main databases, 3 public folder databases and a journal database.

One mail database for the past week has been filling up the transaction logs almost nightly and I can't figure out why. DB4 is mounted on Exchange server 02 in the DAG and has database copies on Production 03, DR 02 and the LAG. There are 1Tb drives for each server's folder where the DB resides. I DO have Circular Logging enabled for that database.

Daily, one of the servers that DB4 resides on fills up its drive and I have to purge the logs manually. (I use eseutil /mk and manually delete all the logs before the reported Checkpoint file) Then, like clockwork, after I clean those out, the LAG server reports being full a day or two later. I'm in a loop of chasing log files.

What steps can I do to troubleshoot why this one database is filling up so many transaction logs when Circular Logging is enabled and shouldn't be doing this? I've always kept a fairly comfortable 60% usage on the drives until last week, now I can't seem to keep the database up because I'm chasing log files.